# Inserting facebook like button

Tags: facebook-like

Say I have a blogging site `http://www.example.com` using custom cms, and I want each content in the site to display a like button. I have been able to add a mod that inserts code snippets in each page, incliding the like code, but how do I go about differentiating the likes from each different post because as I recall, the facebook like code requires a `src="http://www.example.com"`, how do I make the `src` value unique for each page like `src="http://www.example.com/news/a_news.php"`. How do I achieve this...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer below URL to generate like button for your page. 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Once you are done with settings get Code (SDK script + button code) which looks like below.

like button code for URL http://www.site.com/news/a_news.php

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.site.com/news/a_news.php" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

now you have to dynamically set up like button code for each link.

say for b_news.php button will be

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.site.com/news/b_news.php" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

for c_news.php button will be

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.site.com/news/c_news.php" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

you just have to change data-href= in like button and all set.

Comment: yea but that requires me to do it manually, is there a snippet or something that i have to include which parses the page link to the href attribute automatically?