# How to Show a "Like Page" Button in Facebook Post

Tags: facebook

I have seen in so many facebook posts a "Like Page" Button as in the below image
[image]

I want to know that How Can I Share My Page that the mentioned "Like Page" Button Should Also Appear in the Post?

Comment: possible duplicate of [inserting facebook like button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980943/inserting-facebook-like-button)

Comment: @jdero This is not the duplice your mentioned question. That question belongs to inserting the Like Button into webpage. I just want to show the like button in facebook wall posts.

Comment: I'm confused. You mean on Facebook? Programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Well this cannot be achieved by any technique, it is the image of someone's newsfeed and Facebook does it automatically.

However if you want to post this on your web page, then there is a way.

You must be aware of Facebook's new feature of embedding a post to any web page.

When you embed any post to web page, Facebook Automatically puts this "Like Page" button